# JS If a className redirect to link in that className

Tags: javascript

So i'm trying to find a specific class name and if present in the html code redirect to that link.

HTML example:

```
<div class="class2">
<a href="/random/here-is-a-dunno">
```

The class has no ID just a class name!
And here is my code:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('class2');
var count=0;
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    count++;
    alert(count);
}
```

I don't know how to get the link of that div class and redirect to it.

Comment: Class name return an list of node,so you nedd to specify it like this document.getElementsByClassName('class2')[0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) for this:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('class2');
if( elems.length ) {
    var linkElements = elems[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
    if( linkElements.length ) {
        window.location.href = linkElements[0].href;
    }
}
```

Or you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
var linkElement = document.querySelector('.class2 a');
if( linkElement ) {
    window.location.href = linkElement.href;
}
```

Comment: That capital A bothers me ._.

Comment: @SterlingArcher ok, replaced to lowercase, feel better now? :)

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: elems.getElementsByTagName is not a function.

Comment: @JohnCena sorry, I forgot that `getElementsByClassName` returns elements collection, so you should take first element it can find: `elems[0].getElementsByTagName('a')`, I've edited my answer